# scala collections : map a list and carry some state?

Tags: scala, collections

I seem to run into this problem all the time. I want to modify some of the elements in a list, but I need to keep some state as I do it, so map doesn't work.

Here is an example :

```
scala> val l1 = List("a","b","c","d","e","f","b","c","e","b","a")
l1: List[String] = List(a, b, c, d, e, f, b, c, e, b, a)
```

I want to change the name of any duplicates. so I want to end up with this:

```
List(a1, b1, c1, d, e1, f, b2, c2, e2, b3, a2)
```

Getting the dupes is easy :

```
scala> val d = l1.diff(l1.distinct).distinct
d: List[String] = List(b, c, e, a)
```

Now I'm stuck. I made it work by converting d to a HashMap w/ a count, and writing a function to iterate over l1 and update it & the hash before recursing. Which works fine, but looks kinda ugly to me.

But I've always thought there should be a way to do w/ the collection classes.

Here is the rest of my solution which I don't like :

```
  val m = d.map( _ -> 1).toMap

  def makeIt(ms: Map[String, Int], ol: Iterator[String], res: List[String]=List[String]()) :List[String] = {
    if( !ol.hasNext) return res
    val no = ol.next()
    val (p,nm) = ms.get(no) match {
      case Some(v) => (s"$no$v", ms.updated(no,v+1))
      case None => (no,ms)
    }

    makeIt(nm,ol,res :+ p)
  }

  makeIt(m,l1.iterator)
```

Which gives me what I want

```
res2: List[String] = List(a1, b1, c1, d, e1, f, b2, c2, e2, b3, a2)
```

I feel like I want "mapWithState" where I can just pass something along. Like Fold-ish. Maybe it exists and I just haven't found it yet?

Thanks

-------UPDATE---------

@Aluan Haddad's comment pointed me in this direction. Which destroys order, which is fine for my case. But the "state" is carried by zipWithIndex. I'm looking for a more general case where the state would require some computation at each element. But for this simple case I like it :

```
l1.groupBy(x=>x).values.flatMap( v =>{
    if( v.length <= 1 ) v else {
      v.zipWithIndex.map{ case (s,i) => s"$s${i+1}"}
    }
  })
res7: Iterable[String] = List(e1, e2, f, a1, a2, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, d)
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `groupBy`

Comment: @aluan I guess I could use `groupBy` to only visit the elements that need to be changed (and skip the `match`), but I don't see how it helps me keep state as I change the names?

Comment: I should have said that I was suggesting `groupBy` as an alternative to keeping track of state. So you could write something like `values.groupBy(x => x).map((g => g.zipWithIndex.map(...`

Comment: I think that would work for this case, and be better than what I have. But I'm actually interested in the more generic case where my "state" is more complex than an incrementing int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part is that the `"d"` and `"f"` elements get no modification.

This is what I came up with. It's a bit more concise, code wise, but does involve multiple traversals.

```
val l1: List[String] = List("a","b","c","d","e","f","b","c","e","b","a")

l1.reverse.tails.foldLeft(List[String]()){
  case (res, Nil) => res
  case (res, hd::tl) =>
    val count = tl.count(_ == hd)
    if (count > 0) s"$hd${count+1}" +: res
    else if (res.contains(hd+2)) (hd+1) +: res
    else hd +: res
}
//res0: List[String] = List(a1, b1, c1, d, e1, f, b2, c2, e2, b3, a2)
```

By using `tails`, each element, `hd`, is able to see the future, `tl`, and the past, `res`.

Comment: If I read this correctly, this will only work if there are no more than 3 of the same? I like this pattern though.

Comment: Not so. It will count any number of repetitions.

Comment: so it does. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

A simple but slow version

```
l1.zipWithIndex.map{ case (elem, i) =>
  if (l1.count(_ == elem) == 1) {
    elem
  } else {
    val n = {l1.take(i+1).count(_ == elem)}
    s"$elem$n"
  }
}
```

The next version is longer, less pretty, and not functional, but should be faster in the unlikely case that you are processing a very long list.

```
def makeUniq(in: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
  // Count occurrence of each element
  val m = mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]

  for (elem <- in) {
    m.update(elem, m.getOrElseUpdate(elem, 0) + 1)
  }

  // Remove elements with a single occurrence
  val dupes = m.filter(_._2 > 1)

  // Apply numbering to duplicate elements
  in.reverse.map(e => {
    val idx = dupes.get(e) match {
      case Some(i) =>
        dupes.update(e, i - 1)
        i.toString
      case _ =>
        ""
    }

    s"$e$idx"
    }).reverse
  }
```

The code is easier if you wanted to apply a count to every element rather than just the non-unique ones.

```
def makeUniq(in: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
  val m = mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]

  in.map{ e =>
    val i = m.getOrElseUpdate(e, 0) + 1
    m.update(e, i)

    s"$e$i"
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Instead of `slice` from `0`, why not: `val n = 1 + {l1.take(i).count(_ == elem)}`

Comment: @jwvh Thanks for the suggestion, I have modified the answer.